# How do I add a delay to only one function?

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a rotary encoder which I need to update in real time and I have a max6675 thermocouple module which needs min 250ms delay to update. When I include the thermo function in the loop, the delay is applied to the entire loop, canceling out my encoder function. How can I add a delay to only my thermo function without it applying to the entire loop. I tried adding a fake delay based on millis but the max won't load.

```
void encoders(){
    State = digitalRead(CLK);
    if(State != lastState){
      if(digitalRead(DT) != State){
        setTemp = setTemp + 5;
      }else {
        setTemp = setTemp - 5;
      }
      lastState = State;
    }   
    delay(0);
}


void readTemp(){
  float realTemp = thermo.readFahrenheit();
}

void loop(){
  currentRead = millis();
  if(currentRead > lastRead + readDelay){
    readTemp();
    lastRead = currentRead;
  }
  
  encoders();
  

   Serial.println(setTemp);
   Serial.println(realTemp);

}
```

Comment: Looks like you've already got it. except `delay(0)` doesn't do anything so you can delete it. Also watch out for integer overflow.

Comment: Your `readTemp` function doesn't seem to do anything except set a local variable which can't be accessed anywhere else.

Comment: Relevant: [How can I handle the millis() rollover?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/12587/how-can-i-handle-the-millis-rollover)

Comment: Why did you start a new thread.  The answer is already on your other one.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62900728/how-do-i-put-my-thermocouple-code-in-its-own-function-instead-of-in-the-loop-ard

Comment: @Delta_G In this one he implemented that, but he reads into a local variable and thinks that the solution doesn't work.

Comment: Ok.  The title confused me.  Looked like he was on the same code.

Comment: This line if(currentRead > lastRead + readDelay){. Is not rollover safe.  Use subtraction and write that in the way it’s done in the blink without delay example.

Answer (score 0):

You're really close.  The problem you have now is that you are reading into a local variable that is going out of scope as soon as the readTemp function exits.  Google "C++ variable scope" for more info on how that works.  I am assuming that you also have a global variable by that name since you don't report a compile error from trying to use it in loop.  If that's the case then you want something like this:

I also fixed your timing line to be safe for millis rollover.

```
void readTemp(){
  realTemp = thermo.readFahrenheit();
}

void loop(){
  currentRead = millis();
  if(currentRead - lastRead >= readDelay){
    readTemp();
    lastRead = currentRead;
  }
  
  encoders();
  

   Serial.println(setTemp);
   Serial.println(realTemp);

}
```

You should also remove that delay(0) line from the encoder function.  That line at best does nothing and at worst can cause some weird behavior.